# TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined (jasmine, angular)

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I have an error regarding unit testing in Angular. The error is TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined. For this I used an observable and i tried to test the output of the subscribe. I will appreciate any help! Thank you!

```js
  obs1$: Observable<number>;
  pos=12345;

  constructor(
    private service1: Service) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.obs1$ = this.service1.retrieveData1(this.pos)
      .pipe(
        map(item => item.value || null))

  }
```

```css
 let component: ComponentName;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ComponentName>;

  const serviceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Service',['retrieveData1']);

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ComponentName],
      providers: [{ provide:Service, useValue: {} }
    })
      .overrideComponent(ComponentName, {
        set: {
          providers: [
            { provide: ComponentName, useValue: serviceSpy }
          ]
        }
      })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentName);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
 
 fit('should retrieve value', done => {
    component.pos = 12345;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.obs1$.subscribe(value => {
      expect(value).toEqual(1);
      done();
    })
  })
```

```html
<div *ngIf="obs1$ | async as obs">
    <div [ngSwitch]="obs" class="col-2 p-0">
      <div *ngSwitchCase="0">
         <p>red</p>
       </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After Creating spy you need to return a dummy/mock observable value as well.

code is expecting a Observable so below approach you can try  (in every **it** block which call service you can add this)

```
serviceSpy.retrieveData1.and.returnValue(of('mock value as requires'))
```

or you can mock service like this

```
let serviceSpy= jasmine.createSpyObj('Service', {
    'retrieveData1': of('mock data'),
    'other': 'some val'
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I stored the mock data in a variable and just put it in the place where you have ```of('mock data')```.

Answer (score 2):

You have to return on `serviceSpy.retrieveData1` an observable. Simpelst case create one with something like `serviceSpy.retrieveData1 = of({value: []})` and provide your data.
Because now the mock returns undefined, whereas your component expects an observable to use the function "pipe" on it. Which is not possibile